# WD My Passport Stopped working

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a WD My Passport P/N ends with BBK-01 1TB. I had it for couple of years and it was functioning smoothly on Windows 7 and Win 8.1, before upgrading to Windows 10 it stopped working, the Windows recognize it when connected to USB 3 or 2, it also shows up in "Devices and Printers" but with missing details, the properties windows shows that it is working properly and the HardwareID have some attributes to it, but I can't access it from neither my computer nor the "diskmgmt.msc", the external HDD anyhow, spin then beeps twice with clicks prior to each beep and stop spinning but keep on flashing repeatedly, until disconnected of course.

Is it time for me get a new HDD? And is there a way to get to the HDD? I have more than 800GB of essential data on it.

Comment: Have you tried it on another PC? Sounds like the drive is bad if it starts spinning, clicks, then stops.

Comment: you mean the physical HDD and not the installed driver.

Comment: It's a failing/almost dead drive. Clicking means there's a mechanical problem in your drive. So it may get damaged more and more if you plug it in. Consider recovering your drive if it's very important (there are such services, non-cheap). Also there is a [trick](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112050/recovering-data-from-a-damaged-hard-drive-the-freezer-trick) of recovering data by freezing it, but it's not guaranteed to work. Anyway, that drive is/will not be useful anymore, so consider buying a new drive.

Comment: @Jet thanks, i was considering getting a new hdd soon, but it was surprising that the old one stopped working just like that.
thanks for the feedback.

Comment: WD My Passport is a portable drive and as such it if getting power through the USB cable. If there is something wrong with the cable or the USB port the drive won't able to get the power it need to spin up. Please try using the HDD with a different short USB 3.0 cable. Try connecting it to a different USB port and make sure you are not connecting it through a USB hub. If possible try the HDD on a different computer. If the HDD is still not detected on any of the systems download and run [WD DLG](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=gIMtGH) Quick test.

Comment: thanks @Techpumpkin_WD for the tools and the tip, i plugged in the EHDD, it showed in the tools with size of 0MB, every test succeeded.. obviously not, but still using the same USB cable.

Comment: Try a different cable and if it's still showing the same size you might consider using professional data recovery services to recover your data. If interested have a look at the list of [WD Data Recovery Partners](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=8h859C). You should also check if the HDD is still in warranty [here](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=Sh3hRH).

Answer (score 0):

This most likely indicates physical damage. However, I'd recommend you to try to access it by [uninstalling and re-installing the HDD as a device from Device Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725782.aspx). Another thing you should try is updating the USB hub drivers for your computer from your motherboard manufacturer's website or using the Drivers Pack that came with your mobo. This way you'd be able to back up your files before pulling the plug on the drive. It might also be a good idea to run the tests as @Techpumpkin suggested and check the warranty on the drive [here](http://support.wdc.com/Warranty/warrantyStatus.aspx?lang=en).